# Can I start my Audi a3 after lying up 10 months?

Tags: engine, audi, a3

Can anyone tell me if an Audi a3 is lying up 10 months would the engine be seized??? It's on a slant so would the oil be stuck in a bad position?

Comment: The engine will not seize in 10 months unless it was in a flood during that time.

Answer (score 1):

It may or may not be seized, but putting a spanner on it and rotating the engine is one way to find out.

Before that I would suggest to check that there are no birds nests in the belts, that you have put fresh fuel through the system and have a properly charged battery - you might find it starts fine unless it wasn’t running when it was left.

Once you have it running you need to check the tires and brakes.

You will find a couple of answers that also make good points here: [Could a car left sitting for 6 years ever run again?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/36207/10976)